# SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, radiobuttonlist

I am using a `GridView` and in it I have four columns: `labelID`, `fName`, `lName` and `Grade`. The `Grade` is a simple Pass or Fail `Radiobuttonlist`. Once the data is updated I would like it to pull the data on the next reload to show the selected value if the user has passed or failed. Here is the code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChoices" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblChoices_SelectedIndexChanged" Text='<%# Eval("Grade") %>'>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Pass" Text="Pass"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Fail" Text="Fail"></asp:ListItem>
             </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}
private void BindData()
{
    string connectiongString = "Data Source=WSCJTCSQ1;Initial Catalog=LiquorStore;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectiongString);
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, nickname, Grade FROM Company", myConnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    gvUsers.DataSource = ds;
    gvUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What grades does the SQL return?  Are they all either "pass" or "fail" ?

Comment: Hi Andomar,

The SQL grades are either pass or fail yes.  Is it possible to have the radiobutton already selected by pulling the value from SQL when it's loaded?

Comment: Can the grade also be empty?  If it is, the value will be `DBNull.Value` in C#.  Does it help if you replace `Eval("Grade")` with `Eval("Grade") as string` ?

Comment: Technically the Grades will be null until someone selects Pass or Fail, then it gets placed into the database.  I'm just trying to figure out how to pull that same data on the next page load so the user can see what has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the GridView RowDataBound event for this

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvUsers" OnRowDataBound="gvUsers_RowDataBound"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChoices" runat="server">
                     <asp:ListItem Value="Pass" Text="Pass"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="Fail" Text="Fail"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code**

A very simple company class - Company.cs

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Company> companies = new List<Company>()
        {
            new Company(){ Name = "Toyota", Grade = "Pass"},
            new Company(){ Name = "Form", Grade = "Fail"}
        };

    gvUsers.DataSource = companies;
    gvUsers.DataBind();
}


protected void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
            {
                string grade = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Grade") as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grade))
                {
                    RadioButtonList radio = e.Row.FindControl("rblChoices") as RadioButtonList;
                    radio.Items.FindByValue(grade).Selected = true;
                    //You can use this to select as well - see comments from Andomar
                    //radio.SelectedValue = grade;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Binding with `Text='<%# Eval("Grade") %>'>` would be a lot simpler!  Would that not work?

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line of code: `string grade = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Grade");`

Comment: RadioButtonList does not have any Text property at all.

Comment: You're right.  There seems to be a `SelectedValue` property.  Could that work?

Comment: @Vadim - Sorry, the code was wrong and it was for DataGrid. I have updated the answer and it will work with GridView.

Comment: @Tariqulazam it's still loading the page with blank radiobuttons.

Comment: Can you make sure you data is saved in the database? If you want I can update the answer to include databinding with a simple list of objects.

Comment: I have 2 people in the database right now and both have `Pass` as the Grade.  yeah if you could provide the code I might catch and see what i'm doing wrong.  Thank you so much you are the best!!